Question about offensive warfare in Hinduism
I don’t think offensive war is good in the slightest, nor do I think violence is an acceptable answer, but I’m also not childish enough to think that violence wasn’t a part of life, and conquering lands was a necessary act in the past to get the world where it is today.
Like Islam has offensive Jihad, does Hinduism have anything like that when you’re destroying    others and not just self-defense? Can you tell me about it?

No, there is no concept of offensive warfare. Only defensive war is allowed.
Highest Morality

Tuladhara said, ‘O Jajali, I know morality, which is eternal, with all
its mysteries. It is nothing else than that ancient morality which is
known to all, and which consists of universal friendliness, and is
fraught with beneficence to all creatures. That mode of living which
is founded upon a total harmlessness towards all creatures or (in case
of actual necessity) upon a minimum of such harm, is the highest
morality.’

(Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXII)
